# TFS Rolling Build appears to skip building on the weekend

Tags: tfs

On TFS 2010 we set up a build script to automatically run and deploy to our test environment no more than every 4 hours.  So the trigger of the build definition is "Rolling builds - accumulate check-ins until the prior build finishes" with the check box checked for "Build no more often than every [240] minutes".  The way I'm interpreting this is that if a build happens at 16:25, and there's 3 check-ins in the next 30 minutes (the last happening at 16:52), then the next build will happen at 20:25.

The issue we're seeing is that if this sequence of events happens on a Friday, then the next triggered build doesn't occur until Monday morning. We do have two build agents on their own separate virtual machine from TFS, but all machines are up and running 24/7.

There's nothing that anybody on the team is aware of that would cause this behavior, so we're at a loss for why we're seeing it. Are we simply misunderstanding the meaning of Rolling Build, or is there configuration setting we forgot to check?

**EDIT:** For what it's worth, the entirety of the build & deployment process takes all of 90-120 *seconds*. So there were not any check-ins that occurred while it was still building.

Comment: That sounds strange. Just to make sure, the same scenario, if happens during a weekday other than Friday, would have worked fine? The build machine does work Friday nights and weekends, btw :-)

Comment: @DuatLe agreed. And you are correct that the expected behavior works Monday-Thursday, but Friday evenings seem to throw things off. The build that should happen on Friday evening doesn't happen until Sunday evening or Monday morning (with no add'l check-ins to trigger it).  All the necessary machines are on 24/7, and as far as I'm aware there's no way to have build agents only run during certain times so that's why this behavior is quite odd.

Comment: It's worth making an experiment: set any random day as a bank holiday in your Iteration. Does now the same effect occur?

Answer (score 3):

The Accumulate check-ins means that when you check-in a changeset, if there is no build of this build definition in 240 minutes, TFS will queue a build automatically. But if do not check-in a changeset, no builds will be queued.

Builds should be triggered as you wrote. 3rd build should be triggered after the first check-in after 20:25 build not before 0:25 on Saturday. :)

Try to check if changesets were not checked into the location cloaked in the build definition workspace (or checked into the location not mapped by build definition workspace).

Comment: I don't think "Next build should be triggered after the first check-in after 20:25 build." is correct. In this scenario, if the build that occured at 16:25 finished before 20:25, then the next rolling build will start at 20:25. If the first build finished after 20:25, whenever it finished, the next build would start immediately.

Comment: You're right. Correct is: "3rd build should be triggered after the first check-in after 20:25 build not before 0:25 on Saturday" :)

Comment: Actually the behavior we're seeing is that any check-ins after the the 16:25 build will cause a build to happen at 20:25.  Not the first check-in after 20:25.

Comment: This behavior is correct. Check-ins are accumulated and next build is triggered after 240min