# TFS Rolling Build appears to skip building sometimes

Tags: tfs

Environment: TFS 2010

I met a strange issue on the TFS 2010.

I create a rolling build, and set it should be triggered no more often than every 30 minutes.

Usually, it works fine. I can find the build was triggered several times one day.

Then there is a long vacation and after I came back, the rolling build was not triggered in the last two days.

There is nothing changed for the build definition and TFS server. 
 It is very strange.
 Does anyone know the reason or have the same situation?

BTW, I have a little question for rolling builds. That is, Rolling builds work when there are accumulate check-ins until the prior build finishes. If 1:00 AM, a rolling build was triggered, it will finish at 1:20. At 1:10 some new code was checked in, an other build such as nightly build was triggered before 1:20. Question: Is the rolling build triggered at 1:30?

Comment: What you write is correct, also have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037912/tfs-rolling-build-appears-to-skip-building-on-the-weekend . So it works as expected. While building and the "cooldown" period is active, checkins/builds are acumulated, in order to be executed once the "cooldown" period has run down.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of rolling builds is so they don't build up in a queue, basically it means if anyone checks in while a build is happening it won't trigger a build.

If you set a time, eg 30 minutes, it won't ever build within 30 minutes of a previous build.

For the next build to happen you need to check in again outside of those conditions (eg 30 minutes later)

Comment: Betty, Thanks.  
The problem is that I setup the rolling build, but it does not work even I have a lot of check-ins till now. Is there a service need to be refresh or restarted?

Comment: I don't know which service should be restarted and it isn't better to restart TFS server totally.

Comment: your build server is your tfs server? you should be able to restart it by opening up the tfs admin panel and looking at the build tab.

Comment: Restart service, it works now. But still do not know the root cause.